# Does <%@ Register TagPrefix="widget"... from ASP.NET exist in pure HTML or javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to develop some widgets like asp.net (ascx) in pure html + javascript.
Does it exist in pure html (or java jsf)?

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="widget" TagName="widget_de_prueba" Src="~/widgets/widget_test.ascx"%>
<widget:widget_de_prueba ID="someWidget" runat="server" color_fondo="white"
ancho="200px" largo="150px" mensaje="hola" postMensaje="mundo"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is all asp.net webforms code (read: server-side). It's up to the control to decide how to render, whether HTML, JavaScript, CSS or some combination of the 3.

Answer (score 0):

no. that is not valid html. If you are looking for that sort of thing in vanilla HTML and JavaScript I'd recommend looking into custom web components or using a framework like Polymer.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components

https://www.webcomponents.org/

https://www.polymer-project.org/

(you don't need to use polymer to make custom web components, but it helps with the browser support and has some nice features.)